# AngularJS Bootstrap - push row to the next line inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make bootstrap "jump" to the next row inside ng-repeat.

To clarify, I have something like this:

```
 <div class=row>
   <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="field in fields">
   </div>
  </div>
```

What I want is to jump to the next row based on a condition inside ng-repeat. Like this:

```
[1][2][3]  
[4][5]  
[6][7][8]
```

The catch here is that I have to jump columns inside the column div.

Does anyone know the best way to solve this? Please tell me if my question isn't clear.

Comment: What does  "jump" mean?

Comment: go to the next row without filling all the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

played a bit with ng-class hope that helps 
its a bit confusing how bootstrap class works with angular
http://jsfiddle.net/8n9u54ud/

js:

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.myJson = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
})
```

html:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="i in myJson" ng-class="{'col-sm-4':i!=5, 'col-sm-5':i==5}">
        {{i}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATED

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for. I wanto to skip to the next row based on a condition inside ng-repeat.

Comment: ok i got it you always take pairs of 3? so you skip the row on condition?

Comment: exactly. Some point in the code I want to make like a "new line" and continue on the next row.

Comment: you probably need br with ng-if doent work well with bootstrap though , check my updated fiddle

Comment: didn't really work here because there are many columns in a line.

Comment: check the updated fiddle , its better to play  around with ng-class works on fiddle check if you can make something similar

Comment: This is actually what I did to solve. Using ng-class. It didn't look pretty but it did the work. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: np its a bit tricky though it could break the layout with other bootstrap classes

Comment: I used a custom class to avoid wrong behavior. It is a very specific place that I have to apply this, so I did a very customized kind of thing.